# Does the Configuration file creates and delete temporary files whenever we make a change to it?

Tags: c#, config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I am developing a desktop application and I am using configuration file to store user settings for the application.Please, find below the code to save changes to the configuration file:

```
Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
                if (configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key] != null)
                {
                    configFile.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);

                }
                if (param)
                {
                    configFile.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
                }

                    configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

I store this configuration file at the following path:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\some folder\some folder\some folder

The problem is that at some machine the user has limited rights.And whenever the application tries to save settings to the configuration file it gives the
exception :

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

It seems from the machine logs that Configuration library creates and deletes some temporary file during the save operation.So, how do I avoid that exception?